# How to upgrade from Ipython Notebook .12 to .13 (Linux)?

Tags: linux

I installed using `sudo apt-get install ipython-notebook`. But when I check `ipython notebook --version` it is 0.12.1. I tried `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install ipython notebook`, and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install ipython[all]
```

You are using your linux distribution's package manager, and your linux distribution does not have the latest version in its repository. Usually you have to wait until the next release of your distribution to get new versions of packages beyond incremental upgrades. This is one of the reasons that people tend to use python-setuptools' package manager (i.e. the `easy_install` command). The newest version will be downloaded from [pypi](http://www.pypi.org), the Python Package Index.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. I would upvote if I had the "15 reputation." Have a great day.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You should be able to accept the answer as correct. Click the checkmark below it.

Answer (score 0):

@foobarbecue is correct in suggesting installing from [PyPI](http://www.pypi.org/), but there is a better way of doing so, especially if your distribution is not so up to date (and doesn't use secure communications with the PyPI site).

My recommendation is that you remove `ipython` *and* `python-setuptools`:

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython python-setuptools
```

get and install the latest tools for using PyPI in a secure way as recommended for [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

```
wget  https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

After that use:

```
pip install ipython[all]
```

`pip` has several advantages over `easy_install`, including that it first downloads all dependencies and does not leave you with a half install if some cannot be downloaded. It also allows you to **uninstall** packages installed with `pip`, where `easy_install` cannot uninstall its own installations.